# Oracle DB query grouping based on times

Tags: sql, oracle

```
   I/p 
    21-MAR-14 5:10 PM   21-MAR-14 5:20 PM       web
    21-MAR-14 5:18 PM   21-MAR-14 5:20 PM       mob
    21-MAR-14 5:19 PM   21-MAR-14 5:24 PM       mob

 o/p should be                web           mob
   21-MAR-14 11:30 AM         1              1   
   21-MAR-14 11:35 AM         3              1
   21-MAR-14 11:40 AM         1              1
```

Grouping columns based on difference of times

Comment: Create table with those values and than use it in `FROM` clause and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` your table with values.

Comment: Table may not have these time values. But result should show them

Comment: What if your example started at 12:03 and finished at 12:18; should it be counted in 12:05, 12:10 and 12:15 - but not 12:00? What is your logic for inclusion in a particular time slot?

Comment: That is why I said to create new table that stores `12:00,12:05,12:10` and etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope there will be no other change in requirement :-P 
Changing the query again.
Assuming that you database is Oracle 11g, use this query:

```
WITH  date_table  AS (SELECT to_date('21-MAR-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') ddate FROM dual), --> Your date here
      date_group  AS (SELECT trunc(ddate) + (5/(24 * 60)) * LEVEL ddate
                        FROM date_table
                     CONNECT BY trunc(ddate) + (5/(24 * 60)) * LEVEL <= trunc(ddate) + 1),
      user_table1 AS (SELECT CASE WHEN ut.start_date < td.ddate 
                                  THEN td.ddate 
                             ELSE (SELECT MIN(a.ddate) FROM date_group a WHERE a.ddate >= ut.start_date) 
                             END start_date1, 
                             (SELECT nvl(MIN(b.ddate), td.ddate + 1) FROM date_group b WHERE b.ddate >= ut.end_date) end_date1,
                             start_date, 
                             end_date,
                             ut.apptype
                        FROM user_table ut --> Your table here
                        JOIN date_table td ON trunc(ut.start_date) = td.ddate 
                                           OR trunc(ut.end_date) = td.ddate),
      final_table AS (SELECT ddate, 
                             apptype
                        FROM user_table1 ut1
                       RIGHT OUTER JOIN date_group dg 
                             ON (dg.ddate BETWEEN ut1.start_date1 AND (CASE WHEN ut1.end_date - ut1.start_date > 5/(24*60)
                                                                            THEN ut1.end_date1 
                                                                       ELSE ut1.start_date1 
                                                                       END)))
SELECT *
  FROM final_table
pivot (SUM(1) FOR apptype IN ('web' AS web, 'mob' AS mob))
ORDER BY 1;
```

SQL Fiddle here (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/a7606/2)

Output:

```
|                        DDATE |    WEB |    MOB |
|------------------------------|--------|--------|
| March, 21 2014 00:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 00:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 01:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 02:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 03:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 04:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 05:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 06:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 07:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 08:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 09:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 10:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 11:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 11:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 11:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 11:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 11:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 11:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 11:30:00+0000 |      1 |      1 |
| March, 21 2014 11:35:00+0000 |      3 |      1 |
| March, 21 2014 11:40:00+0000 |      1 |      1 |
| March, 21 2014 11:45:00+0000 |      1 |      1 |
| March, 21 2014 11:50:00+0000 | (null) |      1 |
| March, 21 2014 11:55:00+0000 | (null) |      1 |
| March, 21 2014 12:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 12:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 13:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 14:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 15:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 16:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:10:00+0000 |      1 | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:15:00+0000 |      1 | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:20:00+0000 |      1 |      2 |
| March, 21 2014 17:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 17:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 18:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 19:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 20:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 21:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 22:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:05:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:10:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:15:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:20:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:25:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:30:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:35:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:40:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:45:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:50:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 21 2014 23:55:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
| March, 22 2014 00:00:00+0000 | (null) | (null) |
```

Since I have to use input date multiple times, I have taken a dummy table date_table

```
WITH date_table(ddate) AS 
   (SELECT to_date('21-MAR-2014', 'DD-MON-YYYY') FROM dual), -- Your Date here
```

This portion below(date_group) will materialize a table that would look like

--3/21/2014 12:05:00 AM
--3/21/2014 12:10:00 AM
-- .....
-- .....
--3/22/2014 12:00:00 AM

```
date_group  AS (SELECT trunc(ddate) + (5/(24 * 60)) * LEVEL ddate
                  FROM date_table
               CONNECT BY trunc(ddate) + (5/(24 * 60)) * LEVEL <= trunc(ddate) + 1),
```

This portion will set the start_date and end_date to next 5 minute multiple value

```
  user_table1 AS (SELECT CASE WHEN ut.start_date < td.ddate 
                              THEN td.ddate 
                         ELSE (SELECT MIN(a.ddate) FROM date_group a WHERE a.ddate >= ut.start_date) 
                         END start_date1, 
                         (SELECT nvl(MIN(b.ddate), td.ddate + 1) FROM date_group b WHERE b.ddate >= ut.end_date) end_date1,
                         start_date, 
                         end_date,
                         ut.apptype
                    FROM user_table ut --> Your table here
                    JOIN date_table td ON trunc(ut.start_date) = td.ddate 
                                       OR trunc(ut.end_date) = td.ddate),
```

Query portion below will create date (5 minute group), and apptype

```
  final_table AS (SELECT ddate, 
                         apptype
                    FROM user_table1 ut1
                   RIGHT OUTER JOIN date_group dg 
                         ON (dg.ddate BETWEEN ut1.start_date1 AND (CASE WHEN ut1.end_date - ut1.start_date > 5/(24*60)
                                                                        THEN ut1.end_date1 
                                                                   ELSE ut1.start_date1 
                                                                   END)))
```

The final portion will create the expected result

```
SELECT * 
  FROM final_table
 pivot (SUM(1) FOR apptype IN ('web' AS web, 'mob' AS mob))
 ORDER BY 1;
```

To learn more about pivot, refer [this link](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php)

Comment: what is `STARTDATE` here? Can you tell me how you are using this query? Whether in conjunction with another table or query?

Comment: Your requirement is hard to understand, I have modified the post again and here is the sqlfiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59816/6), just let me know if you are looking something like this, you can modify the script and share the link again here, so that I can analyze what you actually want.

Comment: Filter  `trunc(ddate) = '29-MAR-14'` should go in where condition. I have updated the post again.

Comment: Show me in sql fiddle, how it is giving 30-MAR-14 12:00 AM in all rows.

Comment: See my sql fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59816/11), its not showing anything for '04-APR-14' for the same query that you have given.

Comment: Update the table information(DDL), sample data in the table and expected output in the Original Post, then only correct query can be created.

Comment: Again its confusing, If you want the time list of 288 times irrespective of whether that date is present in your table or not, why don't you just use `SELECT TRUNC(to_date('29-MAR-2014')) + (5/(24 * 60)) * level as DAT
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY trunc(to_date('29-MAR-2014')) + (5/(24 * 60)) * LEVEL <= trunc(to_date('29-MAR-2014')) + 1
` ?? It will generate dates for you.

Comment: I don't know how you are using, I am getting 288 values only, this is sql fiddle for that (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/078e2/130)

Comment: I am afraid that the expected output given by you is not correct, check sql fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/34574/1)

Comment: Changed answer again, check the post.

Comment: Query has become little complicated, but working. Updated the post again.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by generating the times that you want.  Then you left join this list into the rest of your query.  But, your question doesn't have the query.

Here is a way to generate the times:

```
with nums as (
      select 5*(level - 1) as n from dual
      connect by level <= 24*60/5
     ) 
select to_timestamp(to_char(mod(n/60, 24), '00')||':'||to_char(mod(n, 60), '00'), 'HH24:MI')
from nums
```

Comment: 23 should be 24 in the "nums" CTE.